# PHP: get subarray of subarray data from array by key from JSON file

Tags: php, json, php-7.1

I have a JSON file as seen below and i already have i want to create a final array that has the movie name as the key and the actors are the value that the key stores

### JSON file

```
{
    "movies": [{
            "title": "Diner",
            "cast": [
                "Steve Guttenberg",
                "Daniel Stern",
                "Mickey Rourke",
                "Kevin Bacon",
                "Tim Daly",
                "Ellen Barkin",
                "Paul Reiser",
                "Kathryn Dowling",
                "Michael Tucker",
                "Jessica James",
                "Colette Blonigan",
                "Kelle Kipp",
                "Clement Fowler",
                "Claudia Cron"
            ]
        },
        {
            "title": "Footloose",
            "cast": [
                "Kevin Bacon",
                "Lori Singer",
                "Dianne Wiest",
                "John Lithgow",
                "Sarah Jessica Parker",
                "Chris Penn",
                "Frances Lee McCain",
                "Jim Youngs",
                "John Laughlin",
                "Lynne Marta",
                "Douglas Dirkson"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

### Ideal output

```
Array(
["Diner"]=>Array(Steve Guttenberg","Daniel Stern","Mickey Rourke","Kevin Bacon","Tim Daly","Ellen Barkin","Paul Reiser","Kathryn Dowling","Michael Tucker","Jessica James","Colette Blonigan","Kelle Kipp","Clement Fowler","Claudia Cron")
["Footloose"]=>Array("Kevin Bacon","Lori Singer","Dianne Wiest","John Lithgow","Sarah Jessica Parker","Chris Penn","Frances Lee McCain","Jim Youngs","John Laughlin","Lynne Marta","Douglas Dirkson")
```

)

### My code so far

```
$movies = json_decode(file_get_contents("movies.json"),true);

$actors = array();
foreach($movies as $movie){
  $key = "cast";
  echo $movie->$key;
}
```

But when i run my current code php gives me a notice "**Trying to get property of non-object**" Can someone explain why this is happening and how to fix it? the error is on this line:

```
echo $movie->$key;
```

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is untested, but try something like this. (Note access `$movies` like an array, not an object as passed `true` as the second param to `json_decode()`)

```
$movies = json_decode(file_get_contents("movies.json"), true);

$actors = array();
foreach($movies['movies'] as $movie){
  $actors[$movie['title']] = $movie['cast'];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First your json is object that has `movies` property. So you must get movies when decode by getting `movies` property.
Then if second parameter of `json_decode` is true, it returns associated array and not object. If you want to get object, call like this:

```
$json = json_decode(file_get_contents("movies.json"));
$movies = $json->movies;
```

And finally you want to get array with name is title and value is cast.

You can use following code:

```
$json = json_decode(file_get_contents("movies.json"));
$movies = $json->movies;

$actors = array();
foreach($movies as $movie){
    $title = $movie->title;
    $actors[$title] = $movie->cast;
}

print_r($actors); //to see ideal output
```